# How can I check if char* variable points to empty string?

Tags: c, pointers, char

How can I check if `char*` variable points to an empty string?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Check if the first character is '\0'. You should also probably check if your pointer is NULL.

```
char *c = "";
if ((c != NULL) && (c[0] == '\0')) {
   printf("c is empty\n");
}
```

You could put both of those checks in a function to make it convenient and easy to reuse.

Edit:
In the if statement can be read like this, "If c is not zero and the first character of character array 'c' is not '\0' or zero, then...".

The `&&` simply combines the two conditions. It is basically like saying this:

```
if (c != NULL) { /* AND (or &&) */
    if (c[0] == '\0') {
        printf("c is empty\n");
    }
}
```

You may want to get a good C programming book if that is not clear to you. I could recommend a book called "The C Programming Language".

The shortest version equivalent to the above would be:

```
if (c && !c[0]) {
  printf("c is empty\n");
}
```

Comment: @Zack: What `c && c[0]` means? Can you explain it please?

Comment: Personally I would separate the check for a NULL pointer from the check for an empty string; the two aren't really related. "more portable" probably isn't really what you were trying to say, since all of the code you present here is valid C (and C++ as well).

Comment: Writing `c != NULL` instead of just `c` gets you dinged if I'm reviewing the code, because the two are exactly the same (as long as `c` is a pointer) and the shorter form is the standard C idiom.  Nonidiomatic forms should only be used when you want to draw a human reader's attention to something funny going on, but there is nothing funny going on here, so, idiom is preferred.

Comment: One character shorter than your "shortest version" would be `if (c && !*c)`.

Answer (score 16):

My preferred method:

```
if (*ptr == 0) // empty string
```

Probably more common:

```
if (strlen(ptr) == 0) // empty string
```

Comment: Note that the second, "more common" possibility is also unnecessarily slower.

Comment: @jpalecek, the slowness doesn't often matter and `strlen` will be easier to understand if you're not used to the first form.

Comment: @Adban, on this site the best way to thank someone is to hit the uparrow next to the answer :)

Comment: @MarkRansom: You asked me nothing hah! :) take +1.

Comment: What if `ptr` is null?

Comment: @Romário the question specifically asked "points to an empty string", so that's the question I answered; a null pointer is a different thing entirely. You can combine a test for null with the others I gave above, and if you put it first the short-circuiting rules will keep you from dereferencing the null pointer. `if (ptr == nullptr || *ptr == 0)`

Answer (score 9):

Check the pointer for `NULL` and then using `strlen` to see if it returns `0`.
`NULL` check is important because passing `NULL` pointer to `strlen` invokes an **Undefined Behavior**.

Answer (score 6):

An empty string has one single null byte. So test `if (s[0] == (char)0)`

Comment: No need for the `(char)` cast.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!*ptr) { /* empty string  */}
```

similarly

```
if (*ptr)  { /* not empty */ }
```

Comment: @igraczech, hmm, this should work for the case char *str = "";  if (!*str) { printf("empty\n"); }.  did I miss some subtle case?

Comment: Sorry, you're right – it was my stupid C-pointer oversight. I had the case where str was pointing to an address containing '\0' only. So the pointer (*str) was non-null where the value (content of address pointed to by str) was null.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use the strlen function as library functions are implemented in the best way.

So, I would write
   if(strlen(p)==0)  //Empty string

Comment: Great idea, lets iterate over the entire string (which, for all you know, could be 2GB in size) just to find out if it contains at least one character! </sarcasm>

Comment: @KevinBallard while you are right there is no need to be a jerk about it.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a chance:

Try getting string via function gets(string)
then check condition as  if(string[0] == '\0')