# How to search for a string in an array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, string, search, structure

I want to determine the frequency of words passed in the command line arguments, so I defined a structure with a string and it's count, now the problem is when I'm trying to search for the string in the Structure array by comparing the strings using `strcmp()` function, I'm getting `Segmentation Fault`, Here's the code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
  char* word;
  int count;
} argsArray;

int search(argsArray array[] , char* Word , int len){
  for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
    if(strcmp(array[i].word , Word)==0){
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

int main( int argc , char* argv[] ){
  argsArray inputArgs[50];
  int i,p=0,a;
  for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    inputArgs[i].word=NULL;
    inputArgs[i].count=0;
  }
  for( i=1 ; i < argc ; i++ ){
    a = search(inputArgs , argv[i] , argc);

    if(  a== -1 ){
        inputArgs[p].word=argv[i];
        inputArgs[p].count++;
        p++;
    }
    else{
        inputArgs[a].count++;
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i < p; i++){
    printf("%s %d\n",inputArgs[i].word,inputArgs[i].count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to suggest you some corrections.

Firstly, I think you were trying to initialize the array of structures when you wrote this.

```
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    inputArgs[i].word=NULL;
    inputArgs[i].count=0;
}
```

As mentioned in the other answer, this will cause segmentation fault. You can initialize the `input[i].word` with `""`.

Or, in the `search` function, you can check whether `array[i].word` is a `NULL`; and if you find `NULL`, then you immediately return `-1` from the function.

For the second suggestion, your `search` function will become something like this.

```
int search(argsArray array[] , char* Word , int len){
  for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
    if(array[i].word == NULL)
        return -1;
    if(strcmp(array[i].word , Word)==0){
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

[Reference for second suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970617/how-can-i-check-if-char-variable-points-to-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

`inputArgs[i].word=NULL;` and then `search(inputArgs , argv[i] , argc);` which invokes `strcmp(array[i].word , Word)`

meaning you just called `strcmp(NULL, Word)` --> segfault

Comment: Then how to do it, because i want to search for that string and if it's not found, add it and if found then return it's position and increase it's count by 1